# Search and replace outer tag in Atom using REGEX

Tags: html, regex, replace

Using Atom, I'm trying to replace the outer tag structure for multiple different texts within a document. Also using REGEX, which I'm not versed enough to come up with my own solution

HTML to be searched `<span class="klass">Any text string</span>`

Replace it with `<code>Any text string</code>`

My REGEX `(<?span class="klass">)+[\w]+(<?/span>)`

Is there a wildcard to "keep" the [\w] part into the replaced result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a *capture* group to capture the text in between the `<span>` tags during the match, and then use it to build the `<code>` output you want.  Try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
<span class="klass">(.*?)</span>
```

**Replace:**

```
<code>$1</code>
```

Here `$1` represents the quantity `(.*?)` which we captured in the search.  One other point, we use `.*?` when capturing between tags as opposed to just `.*`.  The former `.*?` is a "lazy" or tempered dot.  This tells the engine to stop matching upon hitting the *first* closing `</span>` tag.  Without this, the match would be greedy and would consume as much as possible, ending only with the final `</span>` tag in your text.

Comment: Thanks! Much more cleaner that I thought. I was using the capture group all wrong, to capture the tag to be replaced, and not the string to be retained.